# `Corrupted state at` after upgrade from 0.9.39 to 0.9.43

Tags: runtime-upgrade

I have the following error in the logs:

```
2023-11-20 11:47:02 Corrupted state at `[206, 197, 7, 13, 96, 157, 211, 73, 127, 114, 189, 224, 127, 201, 107, 160, 224, 205, 208, 98, 230, 234, 242, 66, 149, 173, 76, 207, 196, 29, 70, 9]: Error`
2023-11-20 11:47:02 Ignoring empty authority change.
```

I have looked at storage mapping, and it's related to Session.queuedKeys. There seems to be no migration at that point, and the key is identical. The blockchain ran smoothly for about 4000 blocks, and then this error stopped block-producing. I couldn't reproduce it locally.

I think I should revert blocks before the runtime upgrade, but how can the problem be identified and prevented? The storage query returns `<unknown>` for that key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a weird situation. It seems like during deployment, we had some runtime precached in volume, so it deployed with an older version of runtime that was missing beefy. Meanwhile, when we looked into the runtime code, it was populated, so we missed the session key storage migration that corrupted the runtime.

Luckily, it was our private chain that we easily reverted.